# python max function asks for src2 TypeError: Required argument 'src2' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I`m writing small script for dataset preparation using Python 3.5.3. It checks for existing files in folder, if there are those that already been processed it finds the biggest index of that files to start from next one.

I'm stuck at ***max*** function which for some reasons requires ***src2*** parameter, however it`s not necessary.

Here is my code:

```
from cv2.cv2 import *
import numpy as np
import os

def store_raw_images(imgs_path, imgs_type):

imgs_format = '.jpg'

if any([img[0:3] == imgs_type for img in os.listdir(imgs_path)]):
    current_imgs = list(filter(lambda x: x[0:3] == imgs_type, os.listdir(imgs_path)))
    name_index = max(list(map(lambda x: int(x[4:-4]), current_imgs)))
    imgs = list(filter(lambda x: x[0:3] != imgs_type, os.listdir(imgs_path)))
else:
    name_index = 1
    imgs = os.listdir(imgs_path)

for img in imgs:
    try:
        # Grayscaling and resizing
        grayscaled = imread(imgs_path + img, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        resized = resize(grayscaled, (60, 90)) if imgs_type == 'pos' else resize(grayscaled, (500, 600))
        imwrite(imgs_path + imgs_type + '-' + str(name_index) + imgs_format, resized)
        name_index += 1

        # Deleting origin image
        os.remove(imgs_path + img)

    except Exception as e:
        os.remove(imgs_path + img)


store_raw_images('pos/', 'pos')
```

I`m getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "img_converter.py", line 45,
>   in 
>       store_raw_images('pos/', 'pos')   File "img_converter.py", line 24, in store_raw_images
>       name_index = max(tr,[]) TypeError: src1 is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

However, if I put next code fragment outside my function it works absolutely fine and there is no error:

```
if any([img[0:3] == imgs_type for img in os.listdir(imgs_path)]):
        current_imgs = list(filter(lambda x: x[0:3] == imgs_type, os.listdir(imgs_path)))
        name_index = max(list(map(lambda x: int(x[4:-4]), current_imgs)))
        imgs = list(filter(lambda x: x[0:3] != imgs_type, os.listdir(imgs_path)))
```

May somebody help to figure out why it shows so weird behavior?
Please feel free to ask additional information and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden Python's built-in `max()` function with a different implementation, due to the line `from cv2.cv2 import *`.  This is EXACTLY WHY the use of `import *` is discouraged; there's no way to tell when problems like this are going to be caused.

Comment: Appreciate for your help! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
max_ = max; # capture the pointer to the native python function 
from cv2.cv2 import *
```

Call max_() to use the native python max function.